# Quirk when parent's class method accesses the subclass's constants

Tags: ruby, oop

Given the following code:

```
class Parent
  CONSTANT = "Parent"

  def self.do_the_thing
    puts CONSTANT
    puts self::CONSTANT
  end
end

class Child < Parent
  CONSTANT = "Child"
end
```

And the following method calls:

```
puts Parent.do_the_thing
# Parent
# Parent

puts Child.do_the_thing
# Parent
# Child
```

Why doesn't `Child.do_the_thing` print "Child" twice?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The constant lookup algorithm may be simplified to:

1. lexically "outward"
2. "upward" by inheritance

So, it first tries to find the constant in the closest lexically enclosing module / class definition, then the lexically enclosing module definition of that module definition, and so on. If it cannot find the constant there, *then and **only then*** does it look at the inheritance chain.

I don't think that matz has ever provided a formal justification for this algorithm, but this algorithm is similar to the method resolution algorithm in Newspeak, and Gilad Bracha provided the following justification: if you write a method, and you have a value *right in front of you* in the lexically enclosing context, it would be surprising, if it picked up some other value from a completely different part of the system.

Translated to your example: the `CONSTANT` assignment is literally directly above the method definition, it would be surprising to the author of that method, if it didn't pick up the value that is being assigned right in front of his eyes.

In the `self::CONSTANT` case, you skip the lexical lookup part by specifying the start point for the lookup explicitly using the `::` scope resolution operator.

Note: unfortunately, constant lookup is *not* actually that simple. Sadly, I don't know of any good description of it. In her famous ["Three Implicit Contexts"](http://yugui.jp/articles/846) article, yugui wrote she ran out of time and would explain constant lookup in a later article, but unfortunately, she never did.

Answer (score 3):

When you call `do_the_thing` method on the `Child` class, `self` is `Child`, so `self::CONSTANT` is `Child::CONSTANT` ('Child').

When you call `do_the_thing` method on the `Parent` class, `self` is `Parent`, so `self::CONSTANT` is `Parent::CONSTANT` ('Parent').

But when you call just `CONSTANT`, Ruby firstly try to find this constant in the place where `do_the_thing` method is located, it is the `Parent` class for both cases.